# I would like to update the version number of the project each time I push f5 for building

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, msbuild, automation, cruisecontrol.net

### What we currently have:

- SVN as source repository
- MSBuild scripts for building and setting version numbers

  - This version numbers is a combination, properties in the build file, and the latest revision from SVN
- Cruise control to run the build scripts

### What I would like to do:

We have our build scripts updating the version number each time we do the build.  I would like to do that automatically each time we do a build by pressing F5 within visual studio.  So update the GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs with the correct version number, from the revision number in SVN

Comment: Can you not just run the msbuild script as a post-build event in VS?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is with a SVN hook. The version number would only be changed on a commit, so you can write a hook that updates that file as part of the commit.

Or check out this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/svn_visual_studio.aspx

Comment: This looks like a very good way to do that.  Then nobody can forget :)

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading [about this yesterday](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/11/29/incrementing-the-assembly-version-for-each-build-in-tfs-2010.aspx) with regards to builds from TFS 2010. I know it isn't completely applicable to your situation or architecture, but he raises some good points about how to go about your assembly versioning.

More specifically, the author references [this post](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/11/09/tfs-2010-build-number-and-assembly-file-versions-completely-in-sync-with-only-msbuild-4-0.aspx). Again, it is specific to MSBuild, but there are some points that are applicable to assembly versioning in general

**Edit:**

The first link talks about the pros and cons of various approaches including using the date as part of your version number (not particularly useful), but leans towards including the TFS build number as part of the assembly version. He refers to his preferred versioning scheme which allows him to identify quickly and easily what the build relates to (hotfix etc). This link is mainly useful to give you some alternative views on assembly versioning.

The second link is referred to by the first link and has some code examples on how he uses MSBuild to help version his assemblies. This could also give some useful ideas on how to go about it. Maybe combine some of these with a post-build event to achieve your goal.

Comment: Please summarise what the posts actually *say*. If they ever get deleted your answer will become worse than useless.

Comment: @ChrisF - Edited. Hopefully it is now slightly better than useless.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it with the F5 by modifying the project file, and using the MSBUILD.Community.Tasks

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Subversion.SvnInfo Username="$(SvnUserName)" Password="$(SvnPassword)" RepositoryPath="$(SvnPath)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="SvnRevision" />
</MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Subversion.SvnInfo>

<CreateProperty Value="$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(SvnRevision)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="FullVersionNumber" />
</CreateProperty>

<MSBuild.Community.Tasks.AssemblyInfo 
  OutputFile="$(ProjectFolder)\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" 
  CodeLanguage="CS" 
  AssemblyVersion="$(FullVersionNumber)" 
  AssemblyFileVersion="$(FullVersionNumber)" />
<Message Text="Test"/>
</Target>
```